# Putting nodes in the middle of the figure

Tags: tikz-pgf, nodes

I have a figure consisting out of several lines:

```
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[top color=black,bottom color=white] (-2,2) rectangle (2,1.75) node [above] {$n_2$};
    \shade[top color=white, bottom color=black] (-2,0.75) rectangle (2,0.5);
    \draw (-2,2)--(2,2);
    \draw (-2,1.75)--(2,1.75);
    \draw (-2,0.75)--(2,0.75);
    \draw (-2,0.5)--(2,0.5);

    \draw[blue, very thick, ->] (-3,2)--(-1.75,0.75) -- (-0.75,1.75)--(0.25,0.75)--(1.25,1.75)--(3.25,-0.25);
    \draw[red, very thick, ->] (-3,1)--(-1.75,0.75)--(3.25,1.75);
    \draw[green, very thick, ->] (-3,3)--(-1.75,0.75)--(-1.5,0.5)--(-0.5,0);
    \node (-1.5,0.5) {$n_2$};
    \node (10,10) {$n_1$};
    \end{tikzpicture}
```

Now I want to put the node with the name $n_1$ in the middle of the horizontal lines (i.e. at point (0,1)). But regardless of the values I enter there the node does not move, it always stays at the same place as the second node with the name $n_2$. Why? And how can I move it?

Comment: I think you want `\node at (0,1)` instead of `\node (0,1)`. Without the `at` the text following is a label for the node.  While code snippets are useful in explanations, it is always best to compose a fully compilable [MWE](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/questions/228) that illustrates the problem including the `\documentclass` and the appropriate packages so that those trying to help don't have to recreate it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Peter said, you should add `at` to specify the coordinates. However, you don't need these extra nodes. You can add the nodes directly to the "bars" above. You can add nodes to any path, and the rectangle is still a path.

### Output

[image]

### Code

```
\documentclass[margin=10pt]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}

\begin{document}
\begin{tikzpicture}
    \shade[top color=black,bottom color=white] (-2,2) rectangle (2,1.75) node [midway,above, inner sep=6pt] {$n_2$};
    \shade[top color=white, bottom color=black] (-2,0.75) rectangle (2,0.5) node [midway, below, inner sep=6pt] {$n_1$};
    \draw (-2,2)--(2,2);
    \draw (-2,1.75)--(2,1.75);
    \draw (-2,0.75)--(2,0.75);
    \draw (-2,0.5)--(2,0.5);

    \draw[blue, very thick, ->] (-3,2)--(-1.75,0.75) -- (-0.75,1.75)--(0.25,0.75)--(1.25,1.75)--(3.25,-0.25);
    \draw[red, very thick, ->] (-3,1)--(-1.75,0.75)--(3.25,1.75);
    \draw[green, very thick, ->] (-3,3)--(-1.75,0.75)--(-1.5,0.5)--(-0.5,0);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```